# Backend high availability solutions in nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, high-availability, pacemaker

Looking for possibilities / alternatives for backend HA in nginx. At the moment we are using lua-nginx which does not support [HttpUpstream module](https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module/issues/169), which would be first choice for me. I know a bit about [pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/) but not never used it so not sure if it would be good combination with nginx. Any hints, experience?